# what means [dev+1] in aptana project explorer

Tags: aptana3

I have a project hosted on GitHub, the active branch of which is called `dev`. Since yesterday, Aptana shows `[dev+1]` next to the project folder. Before yesterday, it's only shown `[dev]`. What does `[dev+1]` mean?

Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Project Explorer in Aptana 3]

Comment: This seems like something you could find by looking through the Aptana man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from the [Aptana Documentation](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Git#Git-ProjectExplorer): (I highlighted the important note)

> Our Git support will make git-specific modifications to the UI for
>   related projects and files. In particular, unstaged files will
>   typically be shown with a red background color in Project and App
>   Explorer; staged will show with a green BG. Files with any uncommitted
>   changes will show with a * (asterisk) "dirty" indicator, and folders
>   will show the dirty indicator when any file inside it's hierarchy is
>   dirty. Projects will show the current branch inside square brackets to
>   the right of the project name inside the Project Explorer. **The branch
>   name will be followed by a + or - and number if there are committed
>   changes to be pushed or pulled from a corresponding remote.**